# Unable to select dynamically added labels by class name in jquery

Tags: jquery

The HTML code looks like :

```
<label for="13">
  <input id="13" value="13" type="radio" name="choice">S1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
</label>
<label for="14">
  <input id="14" value="14" type="radio" name="choice">S11&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S11&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</label>
<label for="15">
  <input id="15" value="15" type="radio" name="choice">S111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</label>
<label for="16">
  <input id="16" value="16" type="radio" name="choice">S1111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S1111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
</label>
<label for="17">
  <input id="17" value="17" type="radio" name="choice">S11111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S11111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</label>
<label for="18">
  <input id="18" value="18" type="radio" name="choice">S111111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S111111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</label>
<label for="19">
  <input id="19" value="19" type="radio" name="choice">S1111111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S1111111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
</label>
<label for="20" class="activelistchoicerow">
  <input id="20" value="20" type="radio" name="choice">S11111111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S11111111&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</label>
```

I have tried using

```
$('label.activelistchoicerow').each(function() {
  alert("found")
});
```

I have also tried using `document.querySelector("label.activelistchoicerow")` but failed.
Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: If the elements are dynamically added to the DOM, you'll need to run your selector *after* they've been added. Also, don't abuse non-breaking spaces. I'd suggest you use CSS to set the width/padding of the `label` elements instead

Comment: Can you please check my solution ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, the elements are added in the previous event. After that I was trying to select the value using down-arrow key.CSS I need to take care of..Will do that later

Comment: Could you please show more of your CSS code, specifically how you add these `label` elements, and where/when the `each()` call is being made.

Comment: @koushik... This might help you https://jsfiddle.net/yesm2fty/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the solution here is register your event which needs class `activelistchoicerow` after the element with that class created

Comment: how to register event...Any other solution